# After Upgrading React-Native expo SDK to 49 getting errors

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, expo

After upgrading Expo SDK from 48 to 49, expo start works but after bundling i get two types of errors:
1- TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined, js engine: hermes
2- Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

[First Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90lEi.jpg)
[Second Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm9np.jpg)

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I've seen a few people asking something similar, so it'd be great if you could update this if you found a solution. Thanks.

Comment: @DarrylYoung I still have the same issue. Do you know what’s wrong?

Comment: @ShahryarFaraji For me, the issue wasn't actually an issue with Expo or how it was set up, but with multiple third-party dependencies that weren't compatible. In the end, as it was a very old project we were trying to update, we ended up creating a fresh Expo SDK 49 project, and then we moved content across. Not ideal, I know. This "has not been registered" error is a little misleading, and is often related to issue in the app (or in my case, certain dependencies).

https://docs.expo.dev/troubleshooting/application-has-not-been-registered/

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your react-navigation libraries too after upgrading. This is particular to the Drawer navigation. Generally upgrading them will solve this e.g.

```
yarn upgrade @react-navigation/drawer@latest
```

Comment: didn't work Joshua.

Comment: in my case, upgrading from expo sdk 48 to 50, it help me to resolve some of my prblems, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Expo SDK 49 and React upgraded many dependencies.

*first: you should update your dependencies for required versions.
but after this problem you will see many problems but i can give you the solution of this problem. (it may vary depending on the dependencies in your project)*

**you can create index.js on your root folder. and then paste it down code** (in normally its not required for react native but currently the library file is not working for AppRegistry and you're seeing this error)

first: you should update your dependencies for the required versions.
but after this problem you will see many problems but I can give you the solution of this problem. (may vary depending on dependencies in your project)

You can create index.js in your root folder. and then paste the following code (normally not needed for react native but the library doesn't work in AppRegistry)

> App from ./App this mean from App.js you can modify your root app.js file

> 'main' => this app name in your
> android/app/src/java/.../MainActivity.java

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import App from './App';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

// registerRootComponent(App);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
```